# JS and CSS Rendering Issues After .htaccess File URL Rewrite Rule

Tags: javascript, php, css, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using WAMP Server on my PC as a local host. I want to re-write my URL without PHP extension and remove query string(but readable) as from `http://myproject/post.php?page=page_slug` to `http://myproject/post/page_slug` and I should be able to read "page_slug" via `echo $_GET['page'];` on "post.php" page. FOr this purpose, I have a project with a simple hierarchy is shared below.

**Project_Folder:**

- ->css/style.css
- ->image/logo.jpg
- ->js/script.js
- ->.htaccess
- ->index.php
- ->about.php
- ->contact.php
- ->blog.php
- ->post.php
- ->page.php

Now I want to remove all .PHP extensions from my URL so I used the below .htaccess code and it is working fine.

```
# Options is required by Many Hosting
Options +MultiViews

#Remove .PHP Extension And Force Redirect To Without .PHP File Name In URL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^?]*)\?p=(\S+)\s [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

After the above code, I am able to re-write my URLs from `http://myproject/post.php?page=page_slug` to `http://myproject/post?page=page_slug` means .PHP extension is now removed successfully.

Now to make my URL free from query string pattern, I used the below code after the above code in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^?]*)\?p=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

After the above code, I am able to re-write my URLs from `http://myproject/post?page=page_slug` to `http://myproject/post/page_slug` means query string is now removed successfully but my JS and CSS are broken now as shown below.

[image]

But my every file is perfect as when I remove the upper second code set then it is working properly. Also, they are loading fine as shown below.

[image]

I noticed one thing that my CSS and JS files data is now changed with my PHP file data as shown below. Why this is happening...???

[image]

So what is the fix for this...??? Also, remember that I need to read QUERY STRING parameters also in my file.

Comment: That you want to access a URL route *as* a query string looks very suspicious and non-working to me.

Comment: Your error is because your server is sending HTML instead of CSS or JavaScript. Likely a 404 page, and likely you messed up your `.htaccess`.

Comment: Yep, I know that it's due to .htaccess but How to fix it by keeping my target also...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "problem" is that you appear to be using relative URL-paths to your static resources (CSS, JS and images). So this is a client-side URL resolution issue. You should be using root-relative (starting with a slash) or absolute (with scheme + hostname) URLs to your assets so they can be located regardless of URL-path depth. (Note that any requests that your JS makes, eg. AJAX, should also be root-relative or absolute.)

The problem is not so much with `.htaccess`, but when you change the URL from `/post.php?page=page_slug` to `/post/page_slug` then any client-side relative URLs are going to resolve relative to `/post/`, not `/` (the document root) as before.

The request for the JS (and CSS) files result in a 404, so the 404 HTML error document is most probably being parsed as JS and failing (ie. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token: '<'" - due to a `<!DOCTYPE html>` or opening `<html>` tag).

A possible *workaround* (to avoid changing your URLs) is to use a `base` HTML element in the `head` section to indicate what any relative URLs should be resolved relative to, overriding the URL of the current document. However, this has some additional caveats if you are using in-page anchors of the form `href="#element"` - since they will now be resolved relative to the document stated in the `base` element and not the current document.

See also [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters stack that goes into more detail on this:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. I got it working by adding `<base href="http://example.com/">` in my HTML Head. Also to read query parameters, I used another way of parsing the URL and reading the last part as the required parameter as

`$actual_link = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$page = substr($actual_link, strrpos( $actual_link, '/' )+1);
echo $page;`

Thanks for clarifying the issue too.