# How add path to url if the url does not contain substring

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to redirect all requests from
`https://example.com/*` to `https://example.com/test/*` if the URL does not contain the `test` substring.

So far I have these rewrite rules

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/test
RewriteRule ^/?$ /test/$1 [R=301,L] # if the url does not contain test, redirect to url with test

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}% test
RewriteRule ^test?(.*)$ /$1 [L] # mask the fact that the url is not https://example.com/ and instead is https://example.com/test but apache serve the website like if it was on root
```

If I access `https://example.com` it redirects to `https://example.com/test` but gives infinite loop because of the second rule.

How can I combine it, so request to `https://example.com/test*` do not get redirected but those request at `https://example.com/*` do without having to change www root directory and so it will work for all URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

> The test should be in url (for user experience), but the apache should route like if it was not in url and instead the request came to root url, so application routing is preserved internally without having to change the app itself.

Ah, Ok. However, you should be linking to the `/test` URLs within your app (so you do still need to "change the app", despite your last comment), otherwise `/test` isn't actually in the URLs that users and search engines see on the page (they will be *redirected*) and your users will experience an external redirect every time they click one of your links (bad for SEO and user experience).

The "redirect" implemented in `.htaccess` to prefix "old" URLs with `/test` is just for SEO - as with any "old" to "new" URL change. (It should not be required for your app to function - with `/test` in the URL-path - since your internal URLs should already include `/test`.)

Try it like this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Insert "/test" at the start of the URL-path if absent in "direct" requests
RewriteRule %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule !^test/ /test/$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite "/test" URLs back to root
RewriteRule ^test(?:$|/(.*)) /$1 [L]
```

The `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is used to prevent a redirect loop. This is empty on the initial request from the client and set to the HTTP response status after the rewrite (below).

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects and only change to 301 (permanent) when you are sure this is working as intended.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Thank your for reply, but that does not work, I still get infinite redirect, because of the second rewrite rule which I must keep for app to work

Comment: @TheLaw This replaces _all_ of your rules. However.... on second read of your question, it sounds like you want to "mask" the `/test` subdirectory, so you shouldn't be implementing a redirect in the first place and `/test` should not be in the URL?

Comment: The test should be in url (for user experience), but the apache should route like if it was not in url and instead the request came to root url, so application routing is preserved internally without having to change the app itself.

Comment: @TheLaw Ah ok, this would seem to be the opposite of (the more common) directory masking? "without having to change the app itself" - Although you do still need to change the app to include `/test` in your internal URLs - you should not be relying on `.htaccess` to do this if that is what you are implying. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Your solution is almost what I was looking for, but then i broke css and links, so instead I opted out for hybrid solution, where I will use the second original redirect to mask the test in url and then handle the 301 in app through header modification if test is not in url. Closing this question and marking your answer as correct, since you took time to answer

Comment: @TheLaw "but then i broke css and links" - that could be the result of using relative URLs to your static assets (and in your links) - since you are redirecting to a different path depth. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71564372/369434) to the following StackOverflow question: [JS and CSS Rendering Issues After .htaccess File URL Rewrite Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71563233/js-and-css-rendering-issues-after-htaccess-file-url-rewrite-rule)