# redirecting about.php to domain.com/About/ using .htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

When I write `RewriteRule About About.php [L,QSA]` in `.htaccess` to make users access `example.com/About.php` using the following link `example.com/About/`. Users can access it correctly if it was written as `example.com/About` only. If I added more backslack like this `example.com/About/` the CSS files are not loaded. Also, if anyone accessed this link `example.com/About/SomeText` he didn't get error 404 he gets `about.php` page without loading CSS as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule About About.php [L,QSA]
> ```

The *problem* with this rule is that it rewrites any URL that simply contains the word "About". So, `/About/SomeText`, `/AnythingAbout` and `/AbcAboutXyz` are all rewritten to `About.php` which processes the request. (It also rewrites itself, which is another matter!)

You need to be specific and match only requests for `/About` exactly. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^About$ About.php [L]
```

The first argument to the `RewriteRule` directive is a regex that matches against the requested URL-path (less the slash prefix).

The `QSA` flag is not required here.

> If I added more backslack like this domain.com/About/ the CSS files are not loaded.

"backslack" - that is a (forward) "slash" (and not a "backslash" either).

This will happen if you are using relative URL-paths to access your CSS files (and other static resources like images and JS). The relative URL-path is resolved by the *browser* relative to the current URL. eg. If you are linking to your stylesheet with `href="styles.css"` and the current URL in the browser is `/About/SomeText` then the browser will naturally request `/About/styles.css`, not `/styles.css` as you might be expecting (when the URL is simply `/About`).

When rewriting the URL at different path depths you need to use either:

- Root-relative (starting with a slash) URL-paths.
- Absolute URLs (with scheme + hostname).
- Specify a `base` element in the `head` section of the HTML source that tells the browser what URL should be used as the *base* for all relative URLs. Although there are caveats with this approach (as mentioned in the linked question below)

(Although, in restricting the above rule to match `/About` only then this naturally avoids this issue.)

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71564372/369434) to the following question that goes into more detail on this:

- [JS and CSS Rendering Issues After .htaccess File URL Rewrite Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71563233/js-and-css-rendering-issues-after-htaccess-file-url-rewrite-rule)

Comment: Now I totally understand how it works. Thanks a lot.